# Opening Form From Report

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have the following lines of code in 2 different VBA functions in a Module they both have the same aim of opening a form to a specific record;

```
stLinkCriteria = "[ID]=" & Reports![Rpt_Manufacture].[ID]
DoCmd.OpenForm stDocName, , , stLinkCriteria
```

and

```
stLinkCriteria = "[ID]=" & Forms![frmManufactureList]![frm_Products].[ID]
DoCmd.OpenForm stDocName, , , stLinkCriteria
```

How can I change this so I only have one function that I can call from reports or forms and it will open the form to a specific record. I have tried the me! version on reports but I get an 'Invalid use of Me keyword' which I guess is because I can not use it from a Module.

UPDATE #1
Based on the answer below by Thomas G I used this code;

```
Option Compare Database

Public Function CmdOpenProductDetails(ByRef theObject As Object)
On Error GoTo Err_CmdOpenProductDetails

    Dim stDocName As String
    Dim stLinkCriteria As String

    stDocName = "FrmProductDetails"

    stLinkCriteria = "[ProductID]=" & theObject![ProductID]
    DoCmd.OpenForm stDocName, , , stLinkCriteria

Exit_CmdOpenProductDetails:
    Exit Function

Err_CmdOpenProductDetails:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume Exit_CmdOpenProductDetails

End Function
```

And from the Form and Report for the product names I have an onClick event that reads;

```
=CmdOpenProductDetails()
```

However, if I click a product name on a form I get the error message;

> The express On Click you entered as the event property setting
>   produced the following error. The expression you entered has a
>   function contain the wrong number of arguments. (The expression may
>   not result in the name of a macro, UDF or Event Proc) (There may have
>   been an error evaluating the function).

If I click from a report I get the error message;

> MS Access cannot find the object 'CmdOpenProductDetails(). Make sure
>   you have saved it and that you have typed it correctly.

Comment: Eh... You need to actually use VBA when passing parameters... You should pretty much never assign a button to a UDF, but always add VBA that calls the UDF

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth I created an on click event to code that calls the CmdOpenProductDetails UDF but now I get an 'Argument not optional' message

Comment: You should pass `Me` as an argument...

Comment: I tried "Private Sub ProductID_Click(Me)" but I got an Expected identifier error.

Comment: You might want to read a VBA tutorial. That's not how you pass an argument to a sub, and is not valid. You should call it like `Open_Form Me`

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth Just having a crazy moment I know how to pass an argument to a sub, all sorted. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Pass the form byref in a sub

SOmething like

```
Public Sub Open_Form(ByRef theForm As Form)

    Dim stLinkCriteria As String

    stLinkCriteria = "[ID]=" & theForm![ID]
    DoCmd.OpenForm theForm, , , stLinkCriteria

End Sub


Private Sub TestIt()

        Open_Form Forms![frmManufactureList]![frm_Products]

End Sub
```

Note that you might have to tweak it a bit because I dont know the exact context. Maybe you have a subform and so you should pass the mainform instead

But the idea is there

---

UPDATE following Erik proposal:

You can pass either a form or a report as an object  to make it work for both

```
Public Sub Open_Form_or_Report(ByRef theObject As Object)

    Dim stLinkCriteria As String


    stLinkCriteria = "[ID]=" & theObject![ID]


    If TypeOf theObject Is Form Then

        DoCmd.OpenForm theObject , , , stLinkCriteria

    ElseIf TypeOf theObject Is Report Then
        DoCmd.OpenReport theObject , , , stLinkCriteria

    Else
        MsgBox "Error :  the type should be a Form or a Report"

    End


End Sub


Private Sub TestIt()

        Open_Form_or_Report Forms![frmManufactureList]![frm_Products]

End Sub
```

Comment: This won't work for reports, just for forms. You might want to adjust it to work for both. Also, `Open_Report` is an awful name for a sub that only opens a form

Comment: totally agree about the awful name :) As for the rest, I am missing some context to make it work in all cases...as I said, I have just given the idea !

Comment: If you use `Object` instead of `Form` for your argument, it'll just work I think

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth here yago, with a type check as a bonus :)